# Does BIOS have memory of what you plug in to boot?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I tried to boot Fedora from a USB stick in a Dell Laptop with Ubuntu 18.04. Unfortunately, the USB stick couldn't boot, and neither did it in another laptop with Fedora installed, so I guess that there was some problem of the installation process with the USB stick.

However, the strange thing that I noticed is that, if I remove the USB stick, power off the computer, restart it, and then enter the BIOS setup, I can see a new *Fedora* option among the different boot options.

Does BIOS have memory of what you plug in? I am annoyed by this feature and I'd like to remove the *Fedora* option. How can I do this?

Comment: Your question appears to be about Fedora (or BIOS/UEFI settings); however Fedora is neither Ubuntu, nor official flavor of Ubuntu thus off-topic on this site - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   Or are you asking how to remove a setting in your UEFI setup (on a machine that only has Ubuntu installed; sorry I'm unsure)

Comment: Yes, I am asking how to remove a setting in my UEFI setup, (on a machine that only has Ubuntu installed). it doesn't matter that it is Fedora or another distribution that I see as an option. I wonder why there is another option to boot when the usb is unplugged.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer to my question. By entering the boot options, you are given an option to delete boot devices so I can do that inside the BIOS setup. However the question remains as to why a new boot device is added even after the usb stick has been unplugged.

Comment: It has its own memory. You can delete with `sudo efibootmgr -v` & `sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -B`. But you installed your UEFI boot incorrectly. UEFI only directly boots external drives from an ESP on that device using /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. You installed into internal drive, so it created new entry. But then external can only be booted on this one computer.

Comment: @oldfred You said: " You installed into internal drive, so it created new entry..." I did not install anything.The installation of Fedora on the usb stick was done on another computer, let's call it computer 1. I simply plugged in the usb stick on computer 2, the one with ubuntu. And then after, removing the usb, I found that Fedora was among the boot options. But I haven't done anything other than selecting usb drive at startup. It is as if some information was passed and stored in computer 2 when I tried to boot from the usb stick.